# Compensa usar Assembly, C e C++ num mesmo programa?

Tags: c, c++, assembly

Para otimizar e deixar o programa mais rápido, haveria utilidade ou necessidade de eu fazer tudo o que puder em Assembly, o que não puder fazer Assembly, faço em C, e o que não puder fazer em C faço em C++?

Referências:

- https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#overview-mixing-langs
- https://arne-mertz.de/2018/10/calling-cpp-code-from-c-with-extern-c/

Comment: Em casos muito, mas muito (mas muito (...)) específico compensa. Em 99.9% dos casos compensa rever o algoritmo ou a forma que implementou em C++. Para garantir que a linguagem seja um gargalo você precisa garantir que foi bem feito antes. Para garantir que deixará de ser um gargalo em outra linguagem você precisará garantir que será bem feito nela. Na grande maioria das vezes o seu resultado em Assembly não será melhor do que do compilador, então será tempo perdido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quase tudo o que é feito em Assembly fica mais lento que feito em C e C++. É possível fazer mais rápido, mas é muito difícil e isto acontece menos do que as pessoas imaginam.

Na verdade só pessoas ingênuas acreditam nisso e são as que menos poderão fazer o Assembly ser rápido. É verdade que essa ingenuidade fará a pessoa produzir códigos ruins em C ou C++ também.

Para programar bem nessas linguagens é preciso domínio muito grande da computação, elas não são mágicas e qualquer coisa que você fizer deixa tudo rápido, elas podem ser rápidas porque permitem fazer códigos complicados, difíceis e que podem alcançar uma ótima velocidade se tudo estiver certo.

Algumas linguagens não dão esse poder todo, mas também pode facilitar algumas coisas. Já vi C# ser mais rápido que C++ e depois a pessoas que escreveu o código em C++ ir melhorando até conseguir bater o mesmo código em C#. Em C++ levou dias pra criar um código ligeiramente mais rápido, em C# levou minutos, e hoje talvez ele seja mais rápido, na época o compilador e biblioteca do C# era muito ruim, do C++ era boa.

É frequente programadores conseguiram mais velocidade com C# ou até Java fazendo código de forma simples comparado com o que elas fariam em C ou C++ ou mais ainda em Assembly, sem falar na produtividade. Você não conseguirá boa velocidade em linguagens de *script* a não ser que compare com um código muito ruim em C/C++, mesmo isso não é fácil, precisar se esforçar.

Answer (score 2):

Assembly de fato, em tempo de execução, é mais rápido. Porém  é custoso no desenvolvimento e complexo em implementação / manutenção sem contar que seu código fica preso na arquitetura do hardware. Por tanto, dependendo da aplicação, qualquer outra linguagem, compilada ou interpretada será mais rápida. Imagina implementar uma consulta a banco de dados em assembly?

[Mas quando falamos de processamento digital de sinais](https://www.dspguide.com/ch28/5.html) ou desenvolvimento de drivers, assembly pode ser uma solução, uma vez que desejamos no meio de um código C/C++ acessar um periférico ou acessar uma instrução do processador digital de sinais. Contudo não é todo dia que se usa esse tipo de tecnologia e vale lembrar que os compiladores estão cada vez mais otimizados para gerar o código de máquina mais eficiente que o escrito em assembly.